# Validate time format over 24 hours with pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, validation

I trying to find a way to validate Time format but for over 24 hours. I mean if the Time cell just count hours it can exceed 24 hours. Let's say I have this df

```
 Time      Family-name       Name    Sex   Birthdate
 13:34:51  Doe               John    M     1989-09-22
 32:42:02  Dolores           Trevino M     1984-02-18
 28:50:06  Emer              Han     M     1987-12-10
```

I tried using something like:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce').notnull().all()
```

but of course I get errors for the times over 24 hours.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What's wrong with your code? It runs fine with the sample data on my system, giving `False`.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime('32:42:02', format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')` -> `NaT` as expected. Your code works fine. What's your pandas verion? To get pandas version use `pd.__version__`

Comment: @QuangHoang
I would like to know that all the cells in Time row are in this format. HH:MM:SS. I mean that I do not want 24hour format validation. For example 12:42: 59 is a pass, 45:21:45 is a pass, 132:59:59 is a pass. With the provided solution everything above 24 is not a pass

Comment: @QuangHoang Maybe I was not quite clear. Let's say that on the Time section I count hours passed. How can I validate that this specific cell has specific format ?.

Btw, if I remove ```all()```  does not work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regex` pattern to match:

```
pat = '^\d+:\d{,2}:\d{,2}$'
df['Time'].str.match(pat)
```

Or use `pd.to_timedelta`:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'], errors='coerce').notna()
```

The second approach allows `'1 day 1:00:00'`, the first doesn't.